# Authentication Error in username and password

Tags: iphone

Ha ii everybody ,i am doing a reader application in iphone ,my need is to sync text to google-doc and download it when even wanted,i finished it,but my problem is when i put the username and password to google-doc for authentication it shows an error message `GData error Service Forbiddon…."403.4 SSL required"(403)`,whats the meaning of this message?how can i solve this,if anybody knows how to solve this issue please help me as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem .we have to put https instead of http for the url.simple.Need to put (s) in http.every thing works fine for me now.
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you exactly send the request the message indicates that you have to use SSL and thus `https` to access the service instead of http. Depending on how you query the service this may be as simple as changing the URL or quite complicated.

Comment: As long as there is no code to see how you do it now, this cannot be answered.

Comment: sir can you give your mail id,i will send the project,only gogledoc syncing,just 1.3 mb in size.